# Pivoting data based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I wonder if it is possible to pivot the following table:

```
10  A  ddd
24  B  fff
34  B  ddd
12  A  ddd
```

I need to pivot it like this

```
A  B  text
-- -- ----
22 34 ddd
0  24 fff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function for this:

```
select IsNull(A, 0) A, 
  IsNull(B, 0) B, 
  txt
from
(
  select num, let, txt
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  sum(num)
  for let in (A, B)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5649/10)

If your values are known, then you can hard-code them similar to the query above. But if you have an unknown number of values, then you can use dynamic sql to create the query string. Your dynamic sql code would look like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Let) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(Let)+', 0) as '+QUOTENAME(Let) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @colsNull + ', txt from 
             (
                select num, let, txt
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(num)
                for let in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5649/14)

The result of both queries is:

```
|  A |  B | TXT |
-----------------
| 22 | 34 | ddd |
|  0 | 24 | fff |
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle query:

```
SELECT NVL(DECODE(area, 'A', total), 0) A
     , NVL(DECODE(area, 'B', total), 0) B
     , val
FROM
 (
  SELECT area, SUM(id) total, val
    FROM stack_test
  GROUP BY area, val
 )
 /
A   B   VAL
--  --  --
0   24  fff
22  0   ddd
0   34  ddd
```

Comment: This is not good. the ddd rows should have been grouped together.